# Is the the function $f(k) = \frac{k\ln 2}{2\ln k}$ strictly increasing at $k \ge 10$

Tags: functions, derivatives

Is the the function $f(k) = \frac{k\ln 2}{2\ln k}$ strictly increasing at $k \ge 10$ where $\ln$ is the [natural log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm).

I believe that the answer is yes.

Here's my thinking:

- $\dfrac{d}{dk}\left(\frac{k\ln 2}{2\ln k}\right) = \dfrac{\ln 2(\ln k - 1)}{2\ln^2(k)}$
- The conclusion follows since for $k\ge 10$, $\dfrac{\ln 2(\ln k - 1)}{2\ln^2(k)} > 0$

Would I also be right in concluding that since $\dfrac{\ln 2(\ln k - 1)}{2\ln^2(k)} < 1$, it follows that the rate of increase decreases as $k$ increases?

Comment: Does $\ln$ stand for the natural or the base-$10$ logarithm? Also, the constant $
\frac{{\ln 2}}{2}$ can be ignored. It does not change monotonicity.

Comment: The rate of increase does not depend on the magnitude of the first derivative. For example, consider $0.5\sqrt{x^2+1}$. Though the derivative remains under $1$, the rate of increase increases as $x$ increases.

Comment: @Gary Great point.  I have added a clarification to my question.

Comment: Instead, you need to show that the second derivative remains under $0$. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: $\ln k -1>0$ for $k>e$. So $f(k)$ is strictly increasing for $k\geq e$.

Comment: Thanks @Gary @Kyky.!  That really helps.  That's right.  I need to go to the second derivative for the rate of increase.

Comment: @LarryFreeman If you're just interested in whether or not the rate of increase of $f(k)$ will eventually decrease, and not necessarily at what *value* of $k \ge 10$ this will happen, then instead of taking the second derivative, note $\lim_{k \to \infty}f'(k) = \lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{\ln 2(\ln k - 1)}{2\ln^2(k)} = \lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{\ln 2\left(1 - 1/\ln(k)\right)}{2\ln(k)}  = 0$. Since $f'(10) \gt 0$, as you've already pointed out, this shows that $f'(k)$ will eventually decrease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different approach:

Note that $$f(k)=\frac{k\ln2}{2\ln k}=\frac{\ln2^k}{\ln k^2}$$ and for $k \geq10$, clearly $\ln(2^k)$ and $\ln(k^2)$ are both positive and greater than $1$. Moreover, $\ln$ is an increasing function and $2^k> k^2$ for $k\geq 10$ which implies $f(k)$ is strictly increasing for $k\geq 10$.

Comment: With $f_1(k) = \frac{\ln(k^2 + k)}{\ln(k^2)}$ instead, all of the conditions you state are true. However, $f_1(10) \approx 1.020696$ & $f_1(11) \approx 1.018143$. Also, L'Hôpital's rule shows $\lim_{x\to \infty}f_1(x) = 1$. This shows your conclusion, i.e., $f_1(k)$ is strictly increasing for $k \ge 10$, is *false*. The main issue is although $\ln$ is an increasing function with $\frac{d(\ln(x))}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$, its rate of increase goes to $0$. Thus, the $\ln$'s numerator argument *must* be increasing considerably faster than the denominator's one for $f(k)$ to be strictly increasing.